# SQlite WAL-mode in python. Concurrency with one writer and one reader

Tags: python, sqlite, concurrency

I'm trying to share a sqlite3 database between one writer process, and one reader process. However, it does not work, and it seems to me that nothing is being written in example.db.

reader.py

```
import sqlite3
from time import sleep
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db', isolation_level=None)

c = conn.cursor()
while True:
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM statistics")
    try:
        print '**'
        print c.fetchone()
    except:
        pass
    sleep(3)
```

writer.py

```
import sqlite3
from time import sleep
import os

if os.path.exists('example.db'):
    os.remove('example.db')

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db', isolation_level=None)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode=wal')
print c.fetchone()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE statistics (stat1 real, stat2 real)")

stat1 = 0
stat2 = 0.0
while True:
    stat1 += 1
    stat2 += 0.1
    cmd = "INSERT INTO statistics VALUES (%d,%f)" % (stat1, stat2)
    print cmd
    c.execute(cmd)
    #conn.commit()
    c.execute("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint=FULL")
    sleep(0.25)
```

I run writer.py in a background process, and then I run reader.py. This is what it shows:

```
**
(1.0, 0.1)
**
(1.0, 0.1)
**
(1.0, 0.1)
```

(...)

What is the correct (and best) way to set this framework with one reader and one writer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect? You only select the first row of the table. And this is always the same row. The "PRAGMA"-statements have no visible effects here.

Comment: fetchall! I was so sure I was doing something wrong with commits and WAL-mode, that I didn't realize. Thanks!

Comment: One more question: In which context these PRAGMA statements are useful?