# Python SQLite3 Is it possible for two programs to access the same database at the same time?

Tags: python, sqlite

Well, I write two programs. One aims to retrieve data from the web, filter and store the data in the database. And another one aims to retrieve data from this database and do some analysis.

The point is that the data I collected changes frequently, just like the data of the market, which means that I need to write a monitor-program to constantly connect to the db and retrieve data after a small interval, say 2 min. But, if in this way, the other program cannot access the data in the db, since it's been locked.

Is there way to connect the same database at the same time for two programs, one for writing, another for retrieving? Or, is there better way to deal with this situation(namely, frequent writing and retrieving)? I am quite new to database, expecting to get any help :)

Comment: Sounds like a case for WAL journal mode

Comment: Oh, right, thanks! It does meet my requirements, and I found a example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821179/sqlite-wal-mode-in-python-concurrency-with-one-writer-and-one-reader.